# AS3 Preload and play mp4 file

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there any way to preload and play mp4 video file in flash with as3?

I tried the method below but didn't have any luck:

```
var myMovie:Sprite;


    var l:Loader = new Loader();
    l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loop, false, 0, true);
    l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, done, false, 0, true);
    l.load(new URLRequest("video.mp4"));

    function loop(e:ProgressEvent):void
    {
      var perc:Number = e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal;
      percent.text = Math.ceil(perc*100).toString();
    }

    function done(e:Event):void
    {
      removeChild(percent); // was removeChildAt(0) but it make more sense this way
      percent = null;

      myMovie = Sprite(l.content);

      addChild(myMovie);

      l.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loop);
      l.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, done);
      l = null;
    }
```

Comment: All you've done here is attempt to load the file.  You have no video player code at all.  Simply loading the file will not play it.

Comment: You probably want to use the [NetStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#includeExamplesSummary) class